# Angular - Form submission canceled because the form is not connected while trying to display data

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 7, and I tried to display my data from the endpoint

I fount out that nothing is being displayed. So, when I console it, I got this error when I tried to display data.

> Form submission canceled because the form is not connected  4200/#/home:1

I tried the GET request on POSTMAN, it works perfectly.

This is what I have in home

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TSL Client Portal</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

client-profile-list.component.ts

```
     export class ClientProfileListComponent implements OnInit {

      filterModel: any = {};
      clientProfileData: any;

      constructor(
       private clientprofileService: ClientProfileService,
       private toastr: ToastrService,
       private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService
       ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
       this.getClients();
      }

     getClients() {
      this.spinnerService.show();
      this.clientprofileService.getClientLists()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          if (!response['success']) {
                    this.toastr.error(response['message']);
                    return false;
                  }
          this.clientProfileData = response['data'];
          console.log(this.clientProfileData);
        },
        error => {
          this.toastr.error(error);
        }
      );
     }

    }
```

client-profile-list.component.html

```
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr *ngFor="let clientprofile of clientProfileData | let i = index">
                      <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
                    <td>{{clientprofile?.client_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{clientprofile?.client_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{clientprofile?.search_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{clientprofile?.posting_group}}</td>
                    <td>{{clientprofile?.staff_no}}</td>
                    <td>{{clientprofile?.address1}}</td>
                    <td>{{clientprofile?.address2}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

I expect it to display data, but nothing is being displayed.

Comment: Does your console.log displays anything? And could you also share your getClientLists method?

Comment: where is your form at? The error is regarding the component with the form.

Comment: You could also check the network tab in the browser's dev tools and see if the request is going out and that you're getting a response with the data you're expecting.